# is it possible to use python setUp and tearDown to adress this

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to desgin some test case, each test case will do the same operation
like

*testA* do:

insomd moduleX
testing
rmmod moduleX

*testB* do

insomd moduleY
testing
 
rmmod moduleY

is it possilbe to put insmod and rmmod operation into setup and teardown? by parameter or something like that.  I want to use setup/teardown to do the prepare and cleanup operation here but not in the test function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain the "setUp" and "tearDown" Python methods used in test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854658/explain-the-setup-and-teardown-python-methods-used-in-test-cases)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just `import os` and run `os.system('insmod moduleX')` and `os.system('rmmod moduleX')` in your setup and teardown for testA, and *mutatis mutandis* for testB.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1) for how to call external commands in python.

You're going to be changing the os, so if something interrupts your tests before teardown occurs, you could leave your system in an inconsistent state.

Comment: no, I'm not asking if I can put shell command in python script, I'm ask how to use setup and teardown to do the different thing for different test case

Comment: You would need to move them to different test suites.